# Descent of rational algebraic $K$-theory with respect to a special type of blow up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

An abstract blow-up square is the following square:
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
B & \ra{f} & Y\\
\da{g_1} & & \da{g_2}\\
A & \ra{h} & X &\\
\end{array}
$$

such that the square is cartesian, $h$ is a closed immersion of finite presentation. $g_2$ is a proper morphism that induces an isomprhism $(Y\setminus B)_{red}\simeq (X\setminus A)_{red}$. Consider the squares with similar properties except we replace the last condition of isomorphism by requiring $g_2: (Y\setminus B)_{red} \rightarrow (X\setminus A)_{red}$ to be finite etale. Let's call these squares etale blow-up. Have these squares been studied in algebraic $K$-theory? You can assume everything is reduced and also smooth. Does the rational algebraic $K$-theory satisfy etale blow-up descent or are their rational $K$-theory related in any way?

Comment: Seems reasonable; say we work with $KGL$ which represents $KH$ then we have a fiber sequence $j_!j^! \rightarrow id \rightarrow h_*h^*$ and $k_!k^! \rightarrow id \rightarrow f_*f^*$. Now we are comparing $j_!j^!KGL \rightarrow k_!k^!KGL$ which is a map on $G$-theory by https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.03927.pdf. So we ask if the map $j_!j^!KGL \rightarrow k_!k^!KGL$ is an equivalence so we ask if the map on $G$ theory is an equivalence. Seems like, with rational coefficients, it is by transfers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I understand correctly, you are comparing the fibers of the rows to check whether they are homotopy equivalent. Fibers are given by the loop of the $G$-theory of complements of $B$ and $A$. I am having difficulty that why $G$-theory of complements are isomorphic. I know there are transfers associated to etale covers but I thought they induce an injection on the rational $G$-theory from the base to the cover and not necessarily an isomorphism ($G$-theory of cover could be bigger).

Comment: Right - they look injective but could be bigger. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Also $h$ looks like separable Galois alteration. A result of Temkin says that you can desingularize using these guys and "at the charactersitic" alteration. In equicharacteristic $p$, a result of Shane Kelly says that after inverting $p$ $K$-theory has descent for these covers and thus right Kan extended from smooth schemes. So I guess that's something...